# Stacked bar chart may not repect changed colors

Tags: dc.js

For my dc.js dashboard I use a stacked bar chart and a pie chart.
When changing the default colors with

```
dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemePastel1);
```

the pie chart changes the color, but not the stacked bar chart.
Do I missed something?
A [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/svenhe/b2r6zn3m/) is provided to quickly check the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug left over from when charts would set their color defaults separately. [I filed it here.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1564)

Until that's fixed, you can set the colors explicitly for the bar chart:

```
chart
    .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePastel1))
```

[image: consistent pastels]

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/4or7kdgf/7/)

Comment: or even more general with ```chart.colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(dc.config.defaultColors()))```

Comment: Nice! @sven, when you get an answer that solves your problem, please click the green checkmark next to the answer. Not only does it spread some Fake Internet Points™,  it also makes it clear which questions are open, for those of us who follow certain tags.